# CSS grid doesn't seem to work properly on mobile devices

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to use a simple layout, that consists of

1. An image
2. Some text

The text should be on the bottom and all remaining space should be used by the image. It seemed a simple task, but it has been a frustrating journey. Finally, I nailed but this solution doesn't work on mobile devices (Android and/or Chrome).

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ramondeklein/29Lu7kjv/11/)

It looks like this on the desktop:
[image: Desktop view]

Unfortunately, the iPad renders it like this:
[image: iPad view]

The text is barely visible, because the image took all the space. On Android (with Chrome 65 installed) it shows some of the text, but not all of it.
[image: Android view]

I use the following HTML code

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>TEST 123</h1>
    <div class="wrapper img-top">
      <img class="image" src="..." />
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The relevant parts of the CSS looks like this (full code on JSFiddle):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: calc(100vh - 85px);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper.img-top {
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

.wrapper.img-top .image {
  grid-row: 1;
  justify-self: center;
}

.wrapper.img-top .text {
  grid-row: 2;
  justify-self: center;
}

.wrapper img.image {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

I guess that there is a problem with the automatic image sizing, but I don't know what to do next? I want to have it responsive, but it just is not going to work.

Comment: Why don't you use flexbox? It's much easier!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you put fixed height on img-top. Your img is, let's say, 900 px, it's not the same on screen as iPad and desktop. Since you put your image to be 1 fr of height, it is getting bigger as screen is getting smaller. So you have two solutions, as far as I can tell, first is to restrict the size of your image, max-height: 300px;, or try putting overflow auto on .img-top.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jakub Muda for the suggestion about using flexboxes. I have finally fixed the problem by moving to a flexbox and fix the remaining issues.

After switching to a flexbox, I kept the same problem. The image was sized to 100% of the size of the parent wrapper div. I have fixed this by adding `overflow: hidden` to the image, so it will not overflow. This worked fine, but some images were distorted, because the aspect-ratio wasn't properly maintained. Adding `object-fit: contain` fixed this issue.

The complete sample can be found at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramondeklein/29Lu7kjv/25), but for completeness I have added the CSS here as well:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: calc(100vh - 85px);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper .image {
  justify-self: center;
  flex: auto;
  overflow: hidden;      /* Important to make sure the image stays within bounds */
  object-fit: contain;   /* Important to make sure the image keeps its aspect ratio */
}

.wrapper .text {
  justify-self: center;
  flex-basis: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.wrapper img.image {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```